# Webscraping table from site (not able to find table or attribute)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to webscrape the table on http://tickertrak.com/ but I am unable to. The code doesn't read anything in after the table tag and I can't even see it so I'm just super confused. I'm new to webscraping and have only been able to do wikipedia tables so far.

```
import time
!pip install selenium
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("http://tickertrak.com/")
time.sleep(2)

df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source, flavor="bs4")
df = pd.concat(df)
df.drop(index=0, axis=0, inplace=True)
df.to_csv("your_table.csv", index=False)`
```

I am getting errors with the line:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

for webdriverexception. Did I forget the path somewhere?

Comment: Stop asking multiple questions in one go and do not edit your post to include any answer that you have got.

Answer (score 0):

That table is generated dynamically by `JS` (`JavaScript`) so you won't get the data with plain `requests` and `bs4`.

However, you can give `selenium` a shot and combine it with `panadas`.

Here's how:

```
import time

import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("http://tickertrak.com/")
time.sleep(2)

df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source, flavor="bs4")
df = pd.concat(df)
df.drop(index=0, axis=0, inplace=True)
df.to_csv("your_table.csv", index=False)
```

This produces a `.csv` file that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi @baduker I am currently having an issue and getting errors from `driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

Comment: You need to install the driver first. See [this](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/).

Comment: I edited my post to show my code. I do believe I formatted it to download. Perhaps the path is messed up?

Comment: What system are you on?

Comment: I'm using google collab notebook. My plan is to scrape and then dump this in a google sheet. Hope that helps and thanks for the help so far

Comment: Oh, I know nothing about Google Collab. You might want to explore the other answer then.

Comment: So @badukar I switched to working with Anaconda > Jupyter so do you know where to add the path for my chrome driver? in your code?

Comment: I actually don't use Python notebooks, as I run all my code in virtual envs. Anyhow, [this](https://medium.com/@shanyitan/how-to-install-selenium-and-run-it-successfully-via-jupyter-lab-c3f50d22a0d4) might help you set it up. Let me know if the code worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the faster ways how you can get the data using requests module from that webpage as the data are already in the page source within a script tag. All you wanna do now is clean the data before storing them in dataframe.

```
import re
import requests

URL = 'http://tickertrak.com/'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36'
    r = s.get(URL)
    items = re.findall(r"var arrayFromPHP = \[(.*?)\];",r.text)[0]
    trs = re.findall(r"\[(.*?)\]",items)
    for tds in trs:
        print(tds)
```

Output are like:

```
"Options","gamestop corp","gme","1","58662","131","-80","-85","1"
"Options","amc entertainment holdings inc","AMC","1","16290","36","-79","-66","2"
"Options","nokia corp","nok","1","3568","14","-86","-88","3"
"Options","regal-beloit corp","RBC","1","3254","11","-56","-89","4"
"Options","blackberry ltd","BB","1","3002","10","-91","-92","5"
```